# UILocalNotification doesn't send

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to send a `UILocalNotification` like this:

```
func sendNotifiaction() {
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.userInfo = [
            "Identifier": self.identifier!
        ]
        notification.alertTitle = "Alarm!"
        notification.alertBody = "test"
        //notification.soundName = "Temporary-bleep-sound.aiff"
        notification.category = "category"

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
```

I tried to put a break point on this method and it is being called and run, but the notification doesn't sent at all.

Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Did you allow the app to push notifications?

Comment: @Lumialxk I think that's the point, how can I do that?

Comment: Where is your fire date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta to register the Notification first

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

Here's my demo for Notification firing at a specific time

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        let localNotification1 = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification1.alertBody = "Your alert message at 9:00 pm"
        localNotification1.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification1.fireDate = self.getNinePMDate()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification1)
        return true
    }

    func getNinePMDate() -> NSDate? {
        let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
        let now: NSDate! = NSDate()
        let date21h = calendar.dateBySettingHour(21, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: now, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchFirst)
        return date21h
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `didReceiveLocalNotification` in `appdelegate` and you have to show alert view manually with title and message as `alertbody` of your notification.